# Selenium RC is not working with latest google chrome

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, selenium

I am using `selenium RC version-2.21`. Everything was working fine with
old google chrome. Then it gets auto updated. The problem is when i
run the test cases only the command window(the window where you can
see which command is getting executed) is visible.The second
window(AUT) is not visible.
My google chrome version is `18.0.1025.162 m`. Please help with this
issue.

Comment: Did you download also newest chromedriver?

Comment: Yes, Pavel I have downloaded the chromedriver. Can you please tell how to use it with selenium RC?

Comment: You don't use ChromeDriver with RC, only with WebDriver.

Answer (score 2):

Any time Chrome gets updated, you may need a new version of the "chromedriver" interface to it.  That's supplied by the Chrome folks, not by the Selenium folks.  Go to http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list and find the one that matches your browser.

Comment: @Ross.I am new to selenium.. There are tutorials of using chromedriver with selenium webdriver. I am using selenium RC, can you please tell how to use chromedriver with selenium RC?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question.  You don't use ChromeDriver with RC.  As far as I know, it just works automatically.  I use it occasionally, and it doesn't require any special preparation - just specifying `*googlechrome` as the browser name.

Comment: Ross...do we have other solution? That's the compatibility issue..There is need to be a solution..U can't downgrade google chrome..thats making it even more worst..:(

Comment: Thanks Ross, this helped me. I was unable to use chrome 18.0 with selenium2. Just downloaded chromedriver.exe for version 18.0 and provided the path as system property "webdriver.chrome.driver".

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a sentence to maximize the AUT window.

You have to add:

```
seleniumClient.windowMaximize();
```

after starting your selenium client instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error message? Or is the browser just not visible (I assume you mean at all and not that it is just minimized?). 
As [Selenium RC's documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html) suggests, not all browser versions are supported (which clearly sucks in this case for you! =[) so you may have to look at Selenium WebDriver, or wait for a new release of Selenium RC to handle the new Chrome. Sorry this doesn't really solve anything for you!

Comment: I did not get any error message, just the browser got minimized. I was using it because of maven integration. Because maven is not working for FF. Can anyone send working POM for FF, Selenium RC and Maven.. It will be of great help..

Comment: Is there not a call to just bring the browser to front and maximise it? Sorry I could not be of more help, I have no experience with maven.

Comment: At last i find the solution.. :)

Comment: What was the solution? You should indicate this somewhere so that someone else may benefit from your question later on. Glad to hear it's solved. :)